# Nodejs Promise "res.end is not a function" error

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I'm refactoring my code to remove a "callback hell" using Promises, but encountered an error that I cannot pass. My code receives list of IDs and processes them making few database calls, that is why I had this "callback hell".
Everything worked fine until Promises. The `res` is equal `0` when I had to respond back to the client.

```
  function processVMDelete(returnedVMIDs){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var mariasqlClient = dbConnection();
        mariasqlClient.query( sqlUpdateDELETE_STATE_ByVMID, [ 
          'DELETE', 
          returnedVMIDs
        ], function(err, rows) {
          if (err){
            reject(err);
          }
          console.log('finish update');
// dont' need to return anything here
          resolve(0);
        });
        mariasqlClient.end();
    });
  }

  function getListExpVM(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      var vmList = [];
      var mariasqlClient = dbConnection();
      mariasqlClient.query( sqlSearch_ByUSERNAMEAndSTATE, [ 
        requesterUsername, 
        'ACTIVE'
      ], function(err, rows) {
        if (err){
          reject(err);
        }
          vmList = filterExpiredVMs(rows);

          var response = {
            status : 200,
            success : 'Successfull',
            data : vmList,
            requester: requesterUsername
          };
          resolve(response);
      }); 
      mariasqlClient.end();
    });
  }



router.post('/processVMs', function(req, res) {
    var returnedVMIDs = JSON.parse(req.body.data);

    processVMDelete(returnedVMIDs)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('done');

        // check if there is more available for the user:
        getListExpVM()
          .then(response => {
            console.log('sending back list of VMs');

//===>>> ERROR HERE: res.end is not a function
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('error', err.message);
            logger.error("Error getting expired VMs: " + err.message);

//===>>> ERROR HERE: res.send is not a function
            res.status(500).send({error: err.message})
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err.message);
        logger.error("Error processing VMs: " + err.message);
//===>>> ERROR HERE: res.send is not a function
        res.status(500).send({error: err.message})
      });
});
```

Comment: That's because of this `processVMDelete(returnedVMIDs).then(res => {...})` - whatever `processVMDelete` is returning you're trying to call `.end` and `.status` methods on it. Rename it to something else so that it uses the original `res` from `router.post("/processVMs", function(req, res) {..})`

Comment: Also, you're still kind of running into a callback-hell like situation here with `Promises`, what version of `Node.js` do you have available? Perhaps you could utilize `async/await` here to make it even simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've redefined `res` with this:

```
processVMDelete(returnedVMIDs)
  .then(res => {...})
```

This will hide the higher scoped `res` associated with the overall request (the one you need to use for `res.end()`).  Change the name of this one to something else like `result` and then change the corresponding references that use this `result`.